# I'm using the CouchbaseMock to do the unit test where a Couchbase client will send a N1QL query to the mock server

Tags: couchbase, indexoutofboundsexception, sql++

Here is the unit test case to save data into mock couchbase and fetch the just saved data using its id:

```
@Test
    public void saveTest() throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("id", 136);
        jo.put("name", "testName");
        jo.put("email", "testEmail");
        String result = couchBaseServerDataAccessImpl.save(jo.toString());

        String queryResult = couchBaseServerDataAccessImpl.getById("136");
        Assert.assertEquals(queryResult, result);


    }
```

And here is the trace:

> com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(0) + length(1)
>   exceeds writerIndex(0): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0,
>   cap: 256)     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.decode(AbstractGenericHandler.java:369)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec$2.decode(MessageToMessageCodec.java:81)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:312)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:286)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:335)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1304)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:356)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:921)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:135)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(0) + length(1)
>   exceeds writerIndex(0): PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0,
>   cap: 256)     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkReadableBytes0(AbstractByteBuf.java:1161)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.readByte(AbstractByteBuf.java:591)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.utils.yasjl.ByteBufJsonParser.readNextChar(ByteBufJsonParser.java:458)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.utils.yasjl.ByteBufJsonParser.parse(ByteBufJsonParser.java:109)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.query.parser.YasjlQueryResponseParser.parse(YasjlQueryResponseParser.java:337)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.query.QueryHandlerV2.decodeResponse(QueryHandlerV2.java:175)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.query.QueryHandlerV2.decodeResponse(QueryHandlerV2.java:62)
>     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.decode(AbstractGenericHandler.java:338)
>     ... 29 more

Comment: Does mock couchbase even support querying through n1ql?